# tensorboard not showing projector data on colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, tensorboard

I'm trying to visualize the embeddings in tensorboard but the projector tab isn't showing anything on colab.

When I downloaded the logs folder to my pc and than ran it locally, it worked perfectly fine. Does anybody have any idea why it isn't working in google colab ?

The command i'm using to show the tensorboard:

`%tensorboard --logdir tmp/`

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

It turns out it wasn't the problem with the code, it was the problem with the browser. Previously i was using safari browser on mac, as soon as i opened colab in chrome, everything worked perfectly fine.